# Command \d invalid in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\d{u} \left( t \right) = Z
\end{equation}
```

Am I missing a package or what?

Comment: Insert a minimal code to show the error. It works here.

Comment: @Sigur Note that the “u” will not be math italic, so “it works here” seems too bold a statement. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that a warning is issued should not be underestimated and, indeed, the form of the “u” is wrong, because it's upright and not math italic.

The `accents` package provides a way to get underaccents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\[
\underaccent{\dot}{u}(t)=Z
\]
\end{document}
```

If you often need the underdot, you can define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\udot}[1]{\underaccent{\dot}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\udot{u}(t)=Z
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, *don't* use `\left` and `\right` in that context; the do nothing good and something bad. Compare the result with `\left` and `\right` added and look carefully at the spacing.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a command `\underdot` by default? I think I might've seen it.